# Замена нескольких строк в файле

Tags: windows, powershell

Пытаюсь сделать, что бы из файла считалась строка из первого массива и заменилась на строку из второго массива, и так несколько раз с разными строками.
Сделал скрипт, но не пойму почему не работает.

```
$OldStrings = @( `
"desktopwidth:i:1440", `
"desktopheight:i:900", `
"winposstr:s:0,1,140,60,1596,999"
)
$NewStrings = @( `
"desktopwidth:i:1734", `
"desktopheight:i:990", `
"winposstr:s:0,1,50,7,1800,1036"
)

$LinesArray = Get-Content -Path 'C:\temp\My Copy\Default.rdp'
$LinesCount = $LinesArray.Count
For($i=0; $i -lt $LinesCount; $i++){

    ForEach ($OldString in $OldStrings) {

        ForEach ($NewString in $NewStrings) {

            If ($LinesArray[$i] -like $OldString) {

                $LinesArray[$i] = $LinesArray[$i] -replace $OldString, $NewString
                Write-Host "`nстрока" $i "принимает значение:" $LinesArray[$i] "`n" -ForegroundColor Gray

            }
        }

    }
```

Файл видимо почему то вообще не считывается. 

После выполнения скрипта вижу только

```
строка 2 принимает значение: desktopwidth:i:1734 


строка 3 принимает значение: desktopwidth:i:1734 


строка 5 принимает значение: desktopwidth:i:1734
```

а в самом файле никаких изменений.

Answer (score 1):

Вы прочитали содержимое в массив строк, меняете содержимое массива $LinesArray, но не сохраняете его в файл.
Добавь в конец:

```
$LinesArray|Set-Content 'C:\temp\My Copy\Default1.rdp' -Encoding Unicode -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Товарищ @alll прав, но хочу немного добавить. Ваши манипуляции можно выполнить и без этого дикого количества вложенных циклов:

```
Get-Content 'C:\temp\My Copy\Default.rdp' | ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace 'desktopwidth:i:1440', 'desktopwidth:i:1734' `
        -replace 'desktopheight:i:900', 'desktopheight:i:990' `
        -replace 'winposstr:s:0,1,140,60,1596,999', 'winposstr:s:0,1,50,7,1800,1036'
} | Out-File 'C:\temp\My Copy\Default.rdp'
```